# The POST method is not supported for route signup. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to run a Sign up form in Laravel, however, upon clicking Signup, I get this error "The POST method is not supported for route signup. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

Now I asked around in Laracast and was instructed to produce two files; 1. routes/web.php file and 2. the Signup HTML Form.

1. routes.web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');

});

Route::get('/signup', 'UserController@postSignUp')->name('signup');
```

2. Signup HTML Form

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <h3 class="text-center text-success">Sign Up!</h3>
            <form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: You said `Route::get('/signup',`. Why is the error message surprising? (Assuming it is surprising … you haven't actually asked a question here.)

Comment: Welcome to SO .... you defined your route as a `GET` route but you are sending a `POST` request .. you are telling your form to send a `POST` request not a `GET` request .. if you want to 'post' this data then have your route be a `POST` route instead of `GET`

Comment: Alright, so I'm now getting an error "Target class [UserController] does not exist."

Comment: you have to import path of your UserController it in web.php file. Like this `use App\Http\Controllers\Backend\UserRoleController;`

Comment: Tried use App\Http\Controllers\UserController, same error, same results.

Comment: If you are using laravel latest version try  `Route::post('/signup', [UserController::class,'postSignUp'])->name('signup');`

Answer (score -1):

Your route is defined as GET request, but your HTML form is attempting to make a POST request.

To resolve this issue, you need to define a route post in web.php like this,

```
Route::post('/signup', 'UserController@postSignUp')->name('signup');
```

And when making post request in laravel, don't forget to add csrf token in your form.

you can add it like this

```
<form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post">
  @csrf
  //rest of your code
</form>
```